# what could be causing lots of errors in my entity framework models' designer file?

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-3.5

I'm having trouble creating/updating EntityFramework models. I have a visual studio 2008 windows forms project the has been compiling and running for years.

Then today, I decide to touch it in order to add a new feature. After a few modifications I decide to update the .edmx file so it can sync with the database, and suddenly I get a lot of different errors in the models designer.vb file.

Below is a sample screen shoot of the error window.

[image]

Now for example when I click on the first error in the screen shoot above, I'm taken to the code in screen shoot below. (where the "**Attribute 'SerializableAttribute' cannot be applied multiple times**" error is.)

This is just one of several different errors.

[image]

I have tried totally deleting the model from the project and then re-creating it a fresh but I'm hitting the same errors again and again.

Comment: Have you extended your classes' definitions with the help of partial classes?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici : No, i haven't

Comment: How many models do you have in your project?

Comment: Could you search your project for all occurrences of `class ImmediateSupervisors`? Please let us know if you find anything in some  other files than the ones in the entity model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have extended your classes' definitions with the help of partial classes and you decorated them with the `Serializable` attribute, you will need to remove this attribute from your manually created partial class.

Also, this answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7809482/674700.

Comment: i haven't added any custom partial class definitions.